# How to use ElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration with spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-autoconfiguration

i want ElasticSearch with autoconfiguration, set application.yml like below:

```
spring:
  elasticsearch:
    rest:
      uris:
      - http://localhost:9200
```

spring boot version : `2.4.3` and using `io.spring.dependency-management`.

maybe `ElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration` use in autoconfig, but reference document so much little.

i want elasticsearch auto-config with a yml data.

[image: my elastic search conf class.]

how can use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `application.yml` is enough. You don't need to create a configuration class, if your goal is simply use the default configurations for the `ElasticsearchRestClient`. Spring boot will identify that `spring-data-elasticsearch` is on the classpath and trigger the auto-configuration using the properties on your `application.yml`.

In fact, you should **not** extend `ElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration`. This is just a auto-configuration class triggered by Spring Boot in order to configure your Elasticsearch Client.

If you need to programmatically supply any configuration for your client through Java, instead of your configuration file, then you can manually configure a client by extending `AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration` to configure yourself a `RestHighLevelClient`

Resources that may help you:

[Spring Data Elasticsearch Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest)

[AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/config/AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration.html)