# SpringBoot can't connect to ElasticSearch. It failed to instantiate SimpleElasticsearchRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, exception, indexing

### Problem

It seems like my SpringBoot application can't connect with ElasticSearch. I keep getting this error whenever i try to run my application:

> UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'filterController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service': Error creating bean with name 'filterService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository': Error creating bean with name 'filterRepository' defined in repository.FilterRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on ElasticsearchRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableElasticsearchRepositoriesConfiguration: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception

### Code info

- I didn't make any changes nor extra-configurations. I'm running ElasticSearch normally
- I did not create a custom configuration file, since [SpringBoot does it automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66745757/how-to-use-elasticsearchrestclientautoconfiguration-with-spring-boot)
- You can find full source-code [here](https://github.com/Dheovani/Uburu/tree/elasticsearch)

This is my Application.java file:

```
package br.com.uburu.spring;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is my FilterController.java file:

```
package br.com.uburu.spring.controller;

// Imports

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/filter")
public class FilterController {

    @Autowired
    private FilterService service;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Filter>> getAll() {
        List<Filter> filters = service.getAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Filter>>(filters, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Filter> getById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        Filter filter = service.findById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Filter>(filter, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // Some other methods
    
}
```

This is the FilterService.java file:

```
package br.com.uburu.spring.service;

// Imports

@Service
public class FilterService {

    @Autowired
    private FilterRepository repository;

    public List<Filter> getAll() {
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        repository.findAll().forEach(filters::add);

        return filters;
    }

    public Filter findById(long id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public Filter save(Filter filter) {
        return repository.save(filter);
    }

    public void delete(long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
    
}
```

My FilterRepository.java file:

```
package br.com.uburu.spring.repository;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

import br.com.uburu.spring.document.Filter;

public interface FilterRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Filter, Long> {}
```

To finish, my project's dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-elasticsearch -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

### Some solutions i've tried:

- Initializing my service and repository variables without the `@Autowired` tag
- Initializing it inside a class constructor, passing the `@Autowired` tag above the constructor
- Running ElasticSearch as admin
- Cleaning Java Language Server Workspace (I'm using VSCode)
- Running `mvn clean install` once again before trying to run my application

### Logs from ElasticSearch

I've noticed this logs in the ElasticSearch's console whenever i try to run my SpringBoot application:

> [2023-04-23T14:57:56,085][WARN ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [DESKTOP-LO4MIAG] received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:9200, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:53007}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost 2 months later, finally managed to solve it. It was a problem with the ssl connection. I've turned it all off and reconfigured it manually in `elasticsearch-8.7.0\config\elasticsearch.yml` to make it work

Answer (score 2):

plz change the index name to the lowercase in class below:

```
package br.com.uburu.spring.utils;

public final class Indices {

    public static final String KEYWORD = "keyword";
    public static final String PATH = "path";
    public static final String FILTER = "filter";
    
}
```

Result:

```
request [HEAD http://localhost:9200/filter] returned 1 warnings: [299 Elasticsearch-7.17.0-bee86328705acaa9a6daede7140defd4d9ec56bd "Elasticsearch built-in security features are not enabled. Without authentication, your cluster could be accessible to anyone. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/security-minimal-setup.html to enable security."]
2023-04-23T14:40:01.302+07:00  WARN 75565 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient      : request [HEAD http://localhost:9200/filter] returned 1 warnings: [299 Elasticsearch-7.17.0-bee86328705acaa9a6daede7140defd4d9ec56bd "Elasticsearch built-in security features are not enabled. Without authentication, your cluster could be accessible to anyone. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/security-minimal-setup.html to enable security."]
2023-04-23T14:40:01.306+07:00  WARN 75565 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient      : request [HEAD http://localhost:9200/filter] returned 1 warnings: [299 Elasticsearch-7.17.0-bee86328705acaa9a6daede7140defd4d9ec56bd "Elasticsearch built-in security features are not enabled. Without authentication, your cluster could be accessible to anyone. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/security-minimal-setup.html to enable security."]
2023-04-23T14:40:01.319+07:00  WARN 75565 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-04-23T14:40:01.433+07:00  INFO 75565 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-04-23T14:40:01.438+07:00  INFO 75565 --- [  restartedMain] br.com.uburu.spring.Application          : Started Application in 1.272 seconds (process running for 6.551)
```

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. I've tried running ElasticSearch as admin and, by your comment, i though it could be a problem with the path in the @RequestMapping tag and changed it to match the values in the index file, but none of it worked.

The only thing i've noticed is the following log in elasticsearch's console whenever i try to run my aplication:

[2023-04-23T14:57:56,085][WARN ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [DESKTOP-LO4MIAG] received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:9200, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:53007}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, It's some steps that I did, you can follow.

1. Open the bin folder in the elastic search folder that you installed previously.
2. Open cmd and run the "elasticsearch.bat" statement. After running successfully, type to the browser, and you can see
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcJbG.png)
3. Let's change your url add "/" + "indexName" backward
   Example in my case :
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jeiI.png)
   Finally, F5 again and you can see, it run successfully
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0ILU.png)

Wish you have done it successfully